# How to get all google places of a certain type in a city?

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-places-api, foursquare

I am building an app in iOS and i want to have a database with all the google places of a certain type(restaurant, bar) in my city. My question is:
1) Is it legal to store the results of google places API requests and use them as you want in the future?
2) If it is legal, is there a way to get all the results i want at once? Do i have to make requests for every little area of the city and get these 20 or 60 results that google places API responses have and then combine them to make my database?
3) Is there something different about these in Foursquare API other than the 50 results per request?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Question 1 can probably be answered by reading the terms and conditions for the API that you are using. Question 2 is answered in the documentation of the API you plan to use. Question 3 can be answered by reading the documentation for the foursquare API. In what way is researching this yourself a problem?